# MS Edge too slow rendering large base64 embedded images like chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, base64, microsoft-edge

I have an intranet app, asp.net mvc 5, entity framework 6 with a requirement to save all files (images included) to database (SQL server varbinary or filestream field). I implemented this by converting images/files to base64 string thinking the bulkiness of the conversion would be compensated by the reduced number of http calls. 
In the controller, I load all files into my model and with a for each loop I render them on a partial view like this:

```
foreach (var f in Model.Files)
    {

   <img class="img-responsive" src=" data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(f.Binaryfield)" />
  }
```

The image files are sometimes large (as high as 3MB) for instance, in Chrome, 15.3mb transferred, including three ~3mb images and everything else on the page was rendered in less than 3 seconds. **But, the issue I am having is with MS Edge** which is rendering the same page in more than 9 seconds. The issue happens as the size of the images to be rendered increase i.e. up to about 1.5mb both browsers would perform similarly above that MS Edge starts lagging. However, when I emulate with older versions say **IE 9 then the performance improves** – it becomes as fast as Google Chrome.

Why is MS Edge unable to handle the load like Chrome?

Also, most don’t recommend base64 for imbedding large images, is there a better alternative for this requirement where blob/filestream (in SQl server) is used to save large images to database?

I have searched for a clue but was not able to find any. 
**Can anyone please suggest a solution? Thanks!!!**

Comment: Edge does not have Security zones, but does filter unsecured images and use mime-sniffing. data uri's are embedded in the page markup, so there should not be any security related lagging between browsers. To debug issues like this in IE first go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Now when you open the IE dev tool, it will list markup, blocked content and security messages in the Console tab of the dev tool. We need to see your client side markup, not your server side MVC code. Possibly you are using images that have been renamed

Comment: @Rob Parsons - Thank you for your comment! This code I posted is actually a client side markup in my PartialView (razor syntax), not server side. I tried the IE options settings  as you suggested but IE did not list any markup for security related or any other message in console. I'll look into the mime-sniffing - let me know if there is anything I can try in the meantime.

Comment: use the View>Source menu in your web browser to view the 'client' markup or Open the dev tool (f12) and view the DOM Explorer.